# No puedo hacer "git push origin master"

Tags: git, git-push, linux-mint, bitbucket

Al hacer git push origin master, tengo el siguiente error:

> "Unauthorized
> fatal: No se pudo leer del repositorio remoto.
>
> Por favor asegúrate de que tengas los permisos de acceso correctos
> y que el repositorio exista."
>
> Ya configuré la claves SSH, lo compruebo con ssh -T git@bitbucket.org:
>
> "authenticated via ssh key.
>
> You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled"

Al clonar mi repo lo hizo sin problemas, a la ahora de subir mis cambios me da ese error del principio, no tengo idea porque he buscado ayuda en la web y sin éxito.

Tambien tengo definido el user.email y user.name

Según la documentación al clonar el repo se cfg la url, a cambio de git init que se debe realizar manualmente. (Para indicar que no tengo error al setear la url)

Estoy con linuxMint y bitbucket

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, @Richie. Veré cómo te puedo ayudar en ello apenas me desocupe, en el caso de que no hayas encontrado alguna solución. Posiblemente, sea más tarde (en la tarde, para ser específico).

Comment: Según [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57998960) (no recuerdo la interfaz de Bitbucket): ¿intentaste agregar tu clave SSH pública en _Tu perfil > Bitbucket Settings > SSH-Keys_?

Comment: Hola @padaleiana, si ya hice eso, allí está la comprobación con ssh -T git@bitbucket.org

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. quedo atento estimado.

Comment: Poder clonar es diferente a poder hacer push en una rama. Puede que haya reglas en el repo que lo impidan. ¿Qué pasa si creas una rama `nombre_del_cambio`, haces commit ahí de tus cambios y les haces push? Podrías hacer luego un Merge Request

Comment: @Alfabravo tengo claro la diferencia entre clonar y push. estoy haciendo todo sobre la master hay reglas para ello? es un repositorio nuevo sin reglas para pruebas con el mismo usuario admin del repo

Comment: Nada de eso que comentas estaba en la pregunta. E igual, hay que revisar la configuracion del repo porque está diciendo que no tienes permitido hacer el push. _Unauthorized_ no es fallo al autenticar o fallo de la URL, es _no tienes permiso_. PD. Es mala práctica trabajar sobre master/main directamente, podrías echarle un ojo a gitflow

Comment: @Alfabravo revisaré GitFlow, hago push directo a la master solo para probar eventos CI/CD

Comment: Hola, @Richie. Necesito que me indique qué sistema operativo está utilizando, si en el repositorio eres el el propietario o colaborador. Esta información es fundamental para elaborar una explicación detallada de cómo solucionar el problema.

Si necesitas ayuda por medio de un Meet, revisa mi perfil y me escribes a mi correo. Una vez que se haya dado solución al problema, publicamos aquí, en el área de respuesta la solución al problema planteado.

Comment: Tome en cuenta que hay una diferencia sutil entre Windows, Linux y Mac a la hora de autenticar el repositorio. Te doy una pista: `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` es uno de los pasos.

Answer (score 0):

lo que sucedia era que usaba una clave ssh de solo lectura.
Ya logré solventar y hacer push a mi rama master, gracias por todo.